# Stopping table & td elements from getting focus

Tags: html, events, focus

In IE it seems that table & td elements will automatically receive focus on a mouse click.

Taken from

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534654%28VS.85%29.aspx

> The following elements can have focus by default but are not tab
>   stops. These elements can be set as tab stops by setting the tabIndex
>   property to a positive integer. applet, div, frameSet, span, table,
>   td.

I have set a tabIndex on a table element, but when one of the td elements of that table is clicked it seems the table loses focus! This seems madness to me, it doesn't happen in Firefox or Chrome.

Has anyone else encountered this and if so is there anyway of stopping this happening?

Thanks,

AJ

Comment: It is still actual now in 2017 and IE11. Why is Microsoft doing it to us?